# ORACLE - How to insert into a table from result of another select statement but with modifications

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I need to insert records into a table from an output of a select statement on the same table, but with some modifications so that the constraints are not violated. This is what I tried

```
--MyTable as three columns C1,C2,C3

Insert into MyTable
(C1, C2, C3)
values
(
  Select 'New Value', C2, C3
  from
 (
   Select C1,C2,C3 from MyTable
 )
)
```

But I get this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The two inner select statements work fine but not the whole thing.

Is this possible to do this with just one sql statement?

Comment: Remove `VALUES` and the parenthesis after it and at the end. You could also write only one `SELECT` -- `SELECT 'New Value', c2, c3 FROM mytable`.

Comment: Ah that worked :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `values` keyword and just use

```
Insert into MyTable
Select 'New Value', C2, C3
  From MyTable
```

because the number of columns in the select list equals to the number of the column of the table, then there's no need to list the column names after table name in the `insert into Mytable` part

Comment: The example above was a simplified one. I do have some logic in the subqueries to filter the result.

Comment: @Silver.Rainbow whatever you prefer, just remove the `values` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
Insert into MyTable (C1, C2, C3)
  Select 'New Value', C2, C3
  from MyTable;
```

The `values` and subqueries are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. But the example above was a simplified one. I do have some logic in the subqueries to filter the result.

Comment: @Silver.Rainbow . . . Well then include that logic as well.